# Lucene 6 How to avoid duplicate entries

Tags: java, lucene

Story:
I need to search for a list of transactionIds be a given username query e.g "Peter M*".

Question: How is it possible to keep the stored transactionIds unique?

I have populated my index with following documents:

```
Document doc = new Document();
doc.add(new StoredField(TRANSACTION_ID, data.getTransactionId()));
doc.add(new TextField(MARCHANT_NAME, data.getName(), Store.NO));
```

I have tried allready two strategies (to avoid duplicate entries) to add a new entry.

1. IndexWriter.updateDocument with a Term holding the transactionId to store.
2. Search for the current transactionId, delete it and store it:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a `StoredField` for the TRANSACTION_ID field. That means it can be retrieved from the index, but is not indexed and can't be searched, and as such, it can't be used as a key to `updateDocument`. Use a `StringField`, instead.

Comment: I see. So it is also possible to use a LongPoint?

Comment: I wouldn't generally recommend it. To do that you would want to avoid `updateDocument`, and instead do a delete followed by adding a new document, so you can use a `Query` to match the documents to remove instead of a `Term`. I usually recommend against numeric fields such as `LongPoint` for identifiers. If it's an identifier that just happens to be made up of digits, use a `StringField`. If it's actually a number (ie. numeric range queries would be useful), then a `LongPoint` would be a good choice.